# Owl carousel not working on product details page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.8

I have used owl carousel for related products in magento2.1.8. It is working fine for desktop and iPad but not working on mobile. On mobile view product base image not display and owl carousel takes large width. If I remove owl carousel base image is coming and remaining page is working fine without scroll.

Comment: can you post the code that you are using for init the carousel? and when you say "not working" what isn't working? is it a display issue, a count issue, a styles issue?

Comment: Hi Circlesix, Check my question I have edited it

Comment: I am also facing same issue. anyone know solution then please share with us! Thanks!

Comment: it's still really hard to know what might be going on with the additional information you provided. But when i was first working with owl carousel and magento 2, i found it hard to get them working right. I decided to use slick instead. It might be worth your time to pop owl out and put slick in, and see if there is just something in the two builds that might not be playing nice. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I have found the issue. The div section with a class of columns is set to display: flex on screen sizes 767px or below.
Obviously, a display setting of flex is better for smaller views, so to overcome this issue, setting overflow to hidden, scroll or auto on the div.column.main has fixed the issue.